# Extract the options of a select in Java + Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to extract the select information and print to the console , already tried in every way , but selenium is unable to find the element , I've used waits implicit and explicit , and still can not .

```
<form style="display:inline" name="productForm" action="lib/general/navBar.php" method="get">

                        <input type="hidden" name="CSRFName" value="CSRFGuard_1364551223">

                        <input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="19838e996a1a94dc508c12fab4ee5c845e4"> Projeto de Teste
    <select style="font-size: 80%;position:relative; top:-1px;" name="testproject" onchange="this.form.submit();">
             <option value="470258" title="Criação de Nova Faixa de Planos Pós PF - 106227 ">
            Criação de Nova Faixa de Planos...</option>
        <option value="469505" title="Limite de Utilização Diferente para Cliente Base que Migrou para Combo Multi - 105942" selected="selected">
            Limite de Utilização Diferente...</option>
        <option value="469489" title="Campanha 0500 Gente Especial 2016 - 106185">
            Campanha 0500 Gente Especial...</option>
        <option value="469477" title="Teste CTC 2016 - 33333333">
            Teste CTC 2016 - 33333333</option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Let me guess - the `form` is inside an iframe?

Comment: The system is TestLink , then yes, this ceretza inside an iframe .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element is inside an `iframe`, you need to be in the context of the `iframe` to be able to find elements inside it. Once inside, find the `select` element (for example, by name), instantiate a `Select` class instance and get the options using `getOptions()` method:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame_name_or_id");

Select select = Select(driver.findElement(By.name("testproject")));
List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();

for (WebElement option : options) {
    System.out.println(option.getText());
}
```